# Error :There is No ViewData

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc4(asp.net(vb.net), razor engine )..
This is annoying me. It works perfectly on the load and if I complete the form and submit it.
It shows the following error.

> There is no viewdata of type'iEnumerable'that has
>   the key CustomerGroupId

In Controller(Get )

```
 Function Create() As ActionResult
    _Engine = CType(HttpContext.Application("Engine"), Engine)
    ViewBag.CustomerSubGroup = New SelectList(_Engine.RteCustomerSubGroupFactory.CodeFactory.Values)
    ViewBag.RateList = New SelectList(_Engine.RteRateListFactory.Values)
    Return View()
End Function
```

In View(.vbhtml)

```
<table>
     <tr><td>Code  </td><td>@Html.TextBox("Code")</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Name</td><td>@Html.TextBox("Name")</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Customer Sub Group Name </td><td>@Html.DropDownList("CustomerSubGroupId")</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Rate List</td><td>@Html.DropDownList("RateList")</td></tr>
     <tr><td>IsDisabled</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("IsDisabled")</td></tr>
```

Shows the error in the line of

```
<tr><td>Customer Sub Group Name </td><td>@Html.DropDownList("CustomerSubGroupId")</td></tr>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use CustomerSubGroup instead of CustomerSubGroupId in your view?

Comment: I think it is "The name of the form field to return.". I wonder how how this would work even when loading the page. I would have though there is @Html.DropDownList("CustomerSubGroupId", ViewBag.CustomerSubGroup); Unless there is some other scripts somehow populating the dropdown - I doubt.

Comment: @Raj... it just updated what i entered in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Action of your Controll,er you have to add a key with the same Id you have used on the View, to apply on the `DropDownList`, for sample:

```
ViewBag.CustomerSubGroupId = New SelectList(_Engine.RteCustomerSubGroupFactory.CodeFactory.Values)
ViewBag.RateList = New SelectList(_Engine.RteRateListFactory.Values)
Return View()
```

in view, you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CustomerSubGroupId")

@Html.DropDownList("RateList")
```

The reason is the `ViewBag` encapsulates the `ViewData`, that's why the message says you do not have the key on the ViewData.